# Assigning an array element to another array element with conditional statement

Tags: javascript

I will give you two strings. I want you to transform stringOne into stringTwo one letter at a time.

Example:

stringOne = 'bubble gum';
stringTwo = 'turtle ham';

Result:
bubble gum,
tubble gum,
turble gum,
turtle gum,
turtle hum,
turtle ham

```
 function mutateMyStrings(stringOne, stringTwo){
  var result = stringOne + "\n";
  var stringOneArr = [...stringOne]; 
  var stringTwoArr = [...stringTwo]; 
  for (var i = 0; i < stringOneArr.length; i++) {
    if (stringOneArr[i] !== stringTwoArr[i]) {
      console.log(stringOneArr);
      stringOneArr[i] = stringTwoArr[i]
      result += (stringOneArr.join('') + "\n")
    }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(mutateMyStrings('dog','cat'));
```

Please Read this, most important.

```
if (stringOneArr[i] !== stringTwoArr[i]) {
  stringOneArr[i] = stringTwoArr[i]
  result += (stringOneArr.join('') + "\n")
}
```

I do not understand why we need the if (stringOneArr[i] !== stringTwoArr[i]) 
statement.  I wrote this code without it and didnt get the corrent answer

```
stringOneArr[i] = stringTwoArr[i]
result += (stringOneArr.join('') + "\n")
```

I get this error:

```
Expected: 'bubble gum\ntubble gum\nturble gum\nturtle gum\nturtle hum\nturtle ham\n', 
instead got: 'bubble gum\ntubble gum\ntubble gum\nturble gum\nturtle gum\nturtle gum\nturtle gum\nturtle gum\nturtle hum\nturtle ham\nturtle ham\n'
```

Can someone tell me why in my for loop I cant just assign stringOneArr[i] = stringTwoArr[i].  to me If i just iterate through the string and assign each string1 element to string2 element than it should come out correctly.

but instead the only way to do it correctly and get corrent output is if I say if string1 element doesnt equal string2 element.  and than I assign it to string1 element to string2 element.  why i dont understand why it wont work with out this conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not wrong, you can just assign `stringOneArr[i] = stringTwoArr[i]`.  But it looks like the testbed you're running it against expects you to skip matching characters.  So it is necessary to check if `stringOneArr[i] !== stringTwoArr[i]` and skip matching characters.  It's just what the test wants.